# Open file into empty buffer in vim

Tags: vim

I remampped `ctrl+v` to open a new tab via `:tabnew`, but it opens an empty buffer and for the life of me I can't find the answer on Google. I just want to open a file in the current buffer like `file /my/file.js`. `file` doesn't work tho. What is the command I am looking for?

Comment: `:e filename` ?  `:edit filename`, that is...

Comment: Do you want to open a file in a new tab or open a file in the current buffer without opening a new tab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is `:edit` aka `:e`, but you can also give `:tabnew` a file argument.

Comment: Thanks! My googling skills failed me because I kept looking up "open" and it kept showing me commands to open a new file or open a file into a new tab. And yes, I know tabnew gives an arg, but I hate having to type `:tabnew` each time :)